# Laravel - не могу вывести в blade установленные мной же куки

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Проблема с отображением куки в представлении blade.php

Когда я устанавливаю куки:

```
setcookie('test2', 'test', time()+86400, '/');
```

То они записываются в куки исправно.

[image: Подтверждение того, что куки записаны и не просрочены]

Делаю dd($_COOKIE['test2']); - всё отлично выводится.

Пытаюсь пробросить эту куку в main.blade.php,

```
                <a href="#" class="d-block"> {{ cookie('test2') }} </a>
```

Получаю вместо значения куки следующее (оно прямо выводится в ссылке вместо значения куки):

> test2=deleted; expires=Sun, 28-Aug-2022 05:41:06 GMT; Max-Age=0;
> path=/; httponly; samesite=lax

Прошу подсказать почему.

Comment: А вам не кажется что `$_COOKIE['test2']` и `cookie('test2')` это разные вещи?

Comment: Хм, до этого не казалось :) Буду рад, если подскажете верный способ, а то это не очень хорошо гуглится, GPT также не знает ответа на это.

Comment: Почитать документацию? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/responses#attaching-cookies-to-responses https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#cookies

Comment: Вы пробовали это? Про вывод в представлении там не вижу информации.
Предположим, нужно создать куку именно так.
Результат одинаков. Создаю ли я через setcookie('test2', 'test', time()+86400, '/');  либо через

$response = response('Hello World')->cookie('test2', 'имя', 3660); 
return $response->send();  

Куки создаются. Притом идентичные. Проблема вывести их в представлении. 

<a href="#" class="d-block"> {{ cookie('test2') }} </a>  


test2=deleted; expires=Sun, 28-Aug-2022 05:41:06 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax

Comment: Ну может вы уже прочитаете документацию про функцию `cookie`?

Answer (score 0):

Я так и не понял, что хотел мне сказать AlexeyTen, поэтому я просто вставил в blade.php {{ $_COOKIE['test'] }} и всё заработало.  Возможно, у Laravel есть более элегантный способ для этого, но работает и работает.
Вопрос закрыт.

Comment:  т.е. ты так и не понял разницы между функцией `cookie` и глобальным массивом `$_COOKIE`?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel:Получить значение Cookie по ключу в шаблоне blade можно следующим способом:

```
{{\Cookie::get('key')}}
```

Установить значение куки в контроллере можно методом

```
Cookie::queue and Cookie::make
```